# Switch between static and dynamic Azure App Configuration service

Tags: spring-cloud, azure-app-configuration, feature-flags

Our Spring Java application should use Azure App Configuration service to manage feature flags.

The problem is that there is [no way to run App Configuration service locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1027362/best-practice-for-handling-local-settings-while-de) through Docker like other feature flags manager products. There is an option the [Java Azure SDK to use local configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-spring-boot?tabs=spring-boot-3) but it is not clear how I can mix it with server configuration. What I would like to have something like this:

*1. Spring local/test profile to use file configuration. Developer to control everything.

2. Any other profiles to use remote Azure App Configuration service.*

When I add `spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web` dependency Java application start trying to connect to the server and the file configuration is ignored.

```xml
        <!-- Global: take feature flags form the server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Local -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-feature-management-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Obviously there is not meant to work together without any additional configuration.

Could you tell me please is it possible such kind of configuration? Is there some magic properties that I can use?
May be there is another way to organise local and qas/prod environments. Please advice.